# Read SMS from GSM Modem with C#

Tags: c#, sms, gsm, modem

I am trying to develop a C# application to send and received sms using Huawei E180 usb dongle. I am able to send sms using AT commands through my application. But i realize that when i send an sms to the dongle, it doesn't show up in the sim card of the dongle.

Instead, it can only be read by the Broandband on Mobile application, so i believe the application is storing the sms somewhere eles rather than the SIM card. Anyone has any solutions to be able to read the existing and incoming sms through a C# application rather than the program that comes with the dongle?

Thanks!

Comment: AT+CPMS controls message storage location. GSMCom is a useful library for this http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/libraries.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dongle is getting the incoming messages from the SIM and probably deleting the SMS messages from SIM memory as SIM have limited memory for SMSs. You need to stop the dongle application in-order to receive message by c# application.

Comment: thanks! i am able to receive the sms on my application now.